# what's the difference between using then in argument and not

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

what's the difference between these two promises one is used in argument other outisde , which one is preferred

```js
fetch(API_URL + "films")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(films => {
    output.innerText = getFilmTitles(films);
  })
  .catch(error => output.innerText = ":(")

fetch(API_URL + "films")
  .then(response => 
    response.json()
      .then(films => {
        output.innerText = getFilmTitles(films);
      }))
  .catch(error => output.innerText = ":(")
```

Comment: The second one is invalid syntax.

Comment: @AKX why would it be invalid syntax? `response.json()` returns a promise, it can be `then()`'d just fine?

Comment: @AKX I mean, only by a closing parenthesis. So.. kinda an unnecessary comment

Comment: You just missed a closing ). I added it in the answer assuming that was a typo.

Comment: Please correct your syntax with proper parens so we're sure what exactly you meant.  Your second option does not have matching parens.

Comment: what i did fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably opinion based. I think the first one is preferred because you won't end up with nested promises and should be easier to read.

To make it more obvious:

```js
fetch(API_URL + 'films')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(films => {
    output.innerText = getFilmTitles(films);
  })
  .catch(error => output.innerText = ':(');
```

vs

```js
fetch(API_URL + 'films')
  .then(response => response.json()
    .then(films => {
      output.innerText = getFilmTitles(films);
    })
    .catch(error => output.innerText = ':(')
  );
```

The number of indentation of the second way would grow while the number of indentations in the first approach is fixed.

Comment: And something that we can make even less problematic by switching to `await` instead of using `then`, removing any and all need for nested functions.

Comment: True. That would be a third option in addition to what OP has mentioned. Assuming OP can use `async/await`

Comment: Thank you for the answer